# Elementor Pro/Rehub theme: How use "featured section" widget?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, dynamic-content

I am completely new to WordPress and Elementor (pro). I am a software developer (mainly C/C++ plus some HTML5/CSS3) trying to teach myself something new while looking for a job. So I am trying to build a web site containing a shop interface (using Elementor pro, WooCommerce and the Rehub theme) and dynamically display highlighted products based on product feeds. This is a learning project for me. I have an abandoned web site project from a friend I am trying to use as template or example to learn WordPress, Elementor Pro and WooCommerce.

The site I am using as an example uses a widget named "featured section", which is from the Rehub theme. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any good tutorial so far on how to use that widget and make it come to life. What I have is this:

[image: raw "featured section" widget]

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

[image: targetted "featured section" widget]

But I have no clue how to add the additional areas to the widget. In the site wreckage I am using as an example, there are two more pages or templates: One having various "featured " widgets:

[image: "Featured " widgets template]

The other page or template seems to serve as input to the widget. It basically contains a huge blog post with several entries, each describing a product:

[image: Featured section source]

The blog page seems to be fed from yet another page containing a bunch of single posts in a "Masonry grid" widget. I haven't found the source of the "post masonry" widget shown below yet.

[image: Posts for blog page]

My question is: How do I put together something like that? How does all that work? How do I link these various pages together? The involved widgets' "data source" etc. fields are all empty, so I cannot see any references between the pages.

Are there any good tutorials or documentations available for this I could work through?

Comment: What's the name of the Plugin which provides the "Featured section" widget and is it capabile for WooCommerce?

Comment: The "featured section" widget is actually from the Rehub theme.

Comment: As it is a paid theme and I can't reproduce it, you should ask the developers.

Comment: So you basically cannot help me with this because you don't own that theme?

Comment: Yes, it's hard so. But how it you get the view of the third image? And what logic is behind the "highlighted products"? Can't you use a special product category or tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out that all these pages aren't really related. The featured section will simply show the five newest (blog) posts added in the WordPress dashboard. To make only certain posts appear, they simply need to have their own category (e.g. "blogpost"). The featured section element has filters that can be used to only show posts of a certain category.